# Laravel : Method does not exists in views

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an object of a class/controller and calling its method in views like

```
$obj = app('App\Http\Controllers\TestController');
$obj->test();
```

Where the test method does exists but i am getting

```
Method [test] does not exist
```

What am i doing wrong here, Its weird

Comment: What output do you get for `dd(app('App\Http\Controllers\TestController'));`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in one line:

```
$obj = app('App\Http\Controllers\TestController')->test();
```

It's working for me.